# Discriminant analysis

Tags: likert, discriminant-analysis

I want to do a discriminant analysis for my study. This study consist of one dependent variable and 8 independent variables. The dependent variable is categorical and has 2 groups. The independent variable are in the form of likert scale. Each independent variable has many items in it in the form of a likert scale. How do we combine all these items to form a independent variable. For example: One independent variable overconfidence has many items and these items are in the form of 5 point likert scale. How can we combine all these items to form the factor overconfidence.

Comment: For each scale that you use there is a manual describing how score is calculated (usually mean or sum of corresponding items) Did you made that computations?

Comment: Is this question really related to discriminant analysis per se?